# Employee model Linked to Django User

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have the Django User model and I created Employee model as below

```
class Employee(models.Model):
         user        = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employees')
         title       = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=6, default='Mr', choices=TITLE, blank=False, null=True)
        firstname   = models.CharField(_('Firstname'), max_length=125, null=False, blank=False)
```

In my sidebar.html I can access the username as `{{ request.user }}` but I want to show the `title` and `firstname` from the Employee model on the sidebar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ForeignKey` to link Employee to User, so from User instance you can access a QuerySet of all related Employee objects (using related_name you provided). Like that:

```
{% for employee in request.user.employees.all %}
    {{ employee.title }} {{ employee.firstname }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you plan to have exactly one Employee object for one User object, it's better to use:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

because then you can easily get `Employee` field values:

```
{{ request.user.employee.title }} {{ request.user.employee.firstname }}
```

Comment: thanks this is what I needed, I changed to OnetoOnefield as it does exactly what I need